# Perforce C++ p4api - build fails in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, perforce

I am trying to build a C++ application which connects to Perforce Server but build fails because it cannot find the p4api libraries.
I am new to C++, Visual Studio and p4api so I probably did something wrong.

I am using Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

**Details:**

I downloaded p4api.zip from ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/bin.mingw64x64/

Notice that the libraries found in p4api.zip are of type **.a** where as in the Chapter 2 of [user guide](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api/p4api.pdf) says that for Windows it should be **.lib**

**Visual Studio Configuration:**

From Visual Studio, Project properties -> Configuration Properties:

- Linker -> General -> Additional Libraries Directories => I specified the directory containing the p4api **.a** files eg `C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ProjectName\ProjectName\lib\p4api`
- Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies => I specified the name of each **.a** file in the order described on user guide. I also added extra libs as described in [this blog](https://www.perforce.com/blog/100119/using-perforce-c-api-windows) eg `libclient.a;librpc.a;libsupp.a;libp4sslstub.a;wsock32.lib;libcmt.lib;oldnames.lib;kernel32.lib;ws2_32.lib;advapi32.lib`
- Linker -> Command Line -> Additional Options => As in user guide eg `/DOS_NT /MT /DCASE_INSENSITIVE`
- C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories => I specified the location of perforce header files eg `C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ ProjectName\ProjectName\include\p4`

**Code**

**Main.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <clientapi.h>

class Main : public ClientUser
{
  public:
    Main();
   ~Main();
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Main.h"

Main::Main()
{
}


Main::~Main()
{
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    ClientApi client;
    Error e;

    client.Init(&e);

    Main ui;
    client.Run("info", &ui);

    client.Final(&e);
}
```

**Build Errors:**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PEConnect, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/MDd' with '/MT'
1>  Main.cpp
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall     Error::~Error(void)" (??1Error@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual   __thiscall ClientUser::~ClientUser(void)" (??1ClientUser@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall Main::~Main(void)" (??1Main@@UAE@XZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::InputData(class StrBuf *,class Error *)" (?InputData@ClientUser@@UAEXPAVStrBuf@@PAVError@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::HandleError(class Error *)" (?HandleError@ClientUser@@UAEXPAVError@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::Message(class Error *)" (?Message@ClientUser@@UAEXPAVError@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::OutputError(char const *)" (?OutputError@ClientUser@@UAEXPBD@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::OutputInfo(char,char const *)" (?OutputInfo@ClientUser@@UAEXDPBD@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::OutputBinary(char const *,int)" (?OutputBinary@ClientUser@@UAEXPBDH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::OutputText(char const *,int)" (?OutputText@ClientUser@@UAEXPBDH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::OutputStat(class StrDict *)" (?OutputStat@ClientUser@@UAEXPAVStrDict@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::Prompt(class StrPtr const &,class StrBuf &,int,class Error *)" (?Prompt@ClientUser@@UAEXABVStrPtr@@AAVStrBuf@@HPAVError@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::Prompt(class StrPtr const &,class StrBuf &,int,int,class Error *)" (?Prompt@ClientUser@@UAEXABVStrPtr@@AAVStrBuf@@HHPAVError@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::ErrorPause(char *,class Error *)" (?ErrorPause@ClientUser@@UAEXPADPAVError@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::Edit(class FileSys *,class Error *)" (?Edit@ClientUser@@UAEXPAVFileSys@@PAVError@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::Diff(class FileSys *,class FileSys *,int,char *,class Error *)" (?Diff@ClientUser@@UAEXPAVFileSys@@0HPADPAVError@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::Diff(class FileSys *,class FileSys *,class FileSys *,int,char *,class Error *)" (?Diff@ClientUser@@UAEXPAVFileSys@@00HPADPAVError@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::Merge(class FileSys *,class FileSys *,class FileSys *,class FileSys *,class Error *)" (?Merge@ClientUser@@UAEXPAVFileSys@@000PAVError@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall ClientUser::Resolve(class ClientMerge *,class Error *)" (?Resolve@ClientUser@@UAEHPAVClientMerge@@PAVError@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall ClientUser::Resolve(class ClientResolveA *,int,class Error *)" (?Resolve@ClientUser@@UAEHPAVClientResolveA@@HPAVError@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::Help(char const * const *)" (?Help@ClientUser@@UAEXPBQBD@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class FileSys * __thiscall ClientUser::File(enum FileSysType)" (?File@ClientUser@@UAEPAVFileSys@@W4FileSysType@@@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class ClientProgress * __thiscall ClientUser::CreateProgress(int)" (?CreateProgress@ClientUser@@UAEPAVClientProgress@@H@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall ClientUser::ProgressIndicator(void)" (?ProgressIndicator@ClientUser@@UAEHXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::SetOutputCharset(int)" (?SetOutputCharset@ClientUser@@UAEXH@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::DisableTmpCleanup(void)" (?DisableTmpCleanup@ClientUser@@UAEXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ClientUser::SetQuiet(void)" (?SetQuiet@ClientUser@@UAEXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ClientApi::ClientApi(void)" (??0ClientApi@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall ClientApi::~ClientApi(void)" (??1ClientApi@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall ClientApi::Init(class Error *)" (?Init@ClientApi@@QAEXPAVError@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall ClientApi::Run(char const *,class ClientUser *)" (?Run@ClientApi@@QAEXPBDPAVClientUser@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall ClientApi::Final(class Error *)" (?Final@ClientApi@@QAEHPAVError@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static char * StrBuf::nullStrBuf" (?nullStrBuf@StrBuf@@0PADA)
1>c:\users\myuser\documents\visual studio  2013\Projects\ProjectName\Debug\PEConnect.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 32 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Additional concerns:**

1)  Did I download the correct p4api? I cannot find a folder specifically for Windows. The only folder which looks more relevant to Windows is bin.mingw

2)  Why the library files are of type **.a** not **.lib**?

3)  Did I set the dependencies correctly on Visual Studio? If yes, why build fails?

Please let me know if you need more details.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you downloaded the 64-bit version, but are building a 32-bit target.

Comment: I think the mingw build is for building with GCC on Windows. Since you are using Visual Studio, try using the Visual Studio API libraries from ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/bin.ntx64/

Comment: Thanks both of you for your replies - they were very helpful. I was using the wrong libraries. Eventually I downloaded p4api_vs2013_static.zip from ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/bin.ntx86/ and worked fine.